# Find and replace using regex and a single input

Tags: javascript, replace, onchange

I am trying to do a simple word changer. For this using a textarea, text and button. I will paste text in the textarea, for example type /red/g,'green' to textbox and click the button but something wrong and I don't know what it is. I'm new thanks for help.

```js
function GetResult() {
  var text = document.getElementById('string-text').value;
  var letter = document.getElementById('string-letter');
  text = text.replace(letter);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="string-text"></textarea>
<br><br>

<input id="string-letter" type="text">
<br><br>

<button id="string-btn" onclick="GetResult();">Change!</button>
```

I got what I want thank you.

Comment: Did you look at how the `replace` function works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Your function creates a new string just to throw it away. Do something with it after the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use a regular expression-alike string, and a replacement value after a comma.
You could use:

- [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) (with [this regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/bgNqjL/1)) to retrieve the desired parts (regex pattern, regex flags, and the replacement word)
- [new RegExp(match, flags)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor  as the first argument of [String.prototype.replace(regularExpression, replacementString)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
// Cache your static elements first
const elText = document.querySelector('#text');
const elReplacement = document.querySelector('#replacement');
const elApply = document.querySelector('#apply');

elApply.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const find = elReplacement.value.trim();
  
  if (!find) return; // Nothing to replace. End function here.
  const [full, match, flags, value] = find.match(/^\/?([^/]+)\/?([gmiyusd]+)?,(.+)$/);
  
  elText.value = elText.value.replace(new RegExp(match, flags), value);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text">Some text with red and multiple red!</textarea><br>
Replace pattern:<br>
<input id="replacement" type="text" placeholder="Your pattern" value="/red/g,green"><br>
<button type="button" id="apply">Apply</button>
```

PS:
your UI would be better rewritten using some *"Find:"* and *"Replace with:"* input fields, than the above.

Answer (score 1):

To replace something you need to replace what and replace with:

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').value = document.body.innerHTML.trim();

function GetResult() {

  const [text, what, to] = 'text what to'
    .split(' ')
    .map(id => document.getElementById(`string-${id}`).value);

  document.getElementById('string-text').value = text.replaceAll(what, to);

}
```

```html
<textarea style="width:100%" rows="7" id="string-text"></textarea>
<label>Replace what
<input id="string-what" type="text" value="Replace">
</label>
<label>Replace to
<input id="string-to" type="text" value="Change">
</label>
<br><br>

<button id="string-btn" onclick="GetResult();">Change!</button>
```